# c3.js messed up display

Tags: javascript, c3.js

I'm trying to display a spline chart with c3.js from a json and displaying the x-axis as a timeseries.

The x axis seems to be messed up. It doesn't recognize the date but instead shows only one column. You can check the image below.

```
window.all = [
    {
        report_date: "2019-03-15 15:00:00",
        swipes_count: 132556,
        results_count: 123,
    },
    {
        report_date: "2019-03-15 15:05:00",
        swipes_count: 142556,
        results_count: 356,
    },
    {
        report_date: "2019-03-15 15:10:00",
        swipes_count: 156556,
        results_count: 678,
    },
    {
        report_date: "2019-03-15 15:15:00",
        swipes_count: 184322,
        results_count: 975,
    },
    {
        report_date: "2019-03-15 15:20:00",
        swipes_count: 194322,
        results_count: 1035,
    },
    {
        report_date: "2019-03-15 15:25:00",
        swipes_count: 198322,
        results_count: 1456,
    }
];

c3.generate({
    bindto: '#' + id, // id of chart wrapper
    data: {
        json: window[key],
        keys: {
            x: 'report_date',
            value: ['swipes_count', 'results_count'],
        },
        labels: true,
        type: 'spline'
    },
    axis: {
        x:{
            type: "timeseries",
            tick:{
                format: "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
            }
        }
    },
    padding: {
        bottom: 0,
        top: 0
    },
});
```

[image: Chart]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add an *xFormat* string in the data configuration (basically the same one as in the tick format declaration) so c3 knows how to parse your date-times

```
        ...
        keys: {
            x: 'report_date',
            value: ['swipes_count', 'results_count'],
        },
        xFormat: "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",
        labels: true,
        type: 'spline'
        ...
```